# ASP.Net Menu CSS Not Applying

Tags: asp.net, css

I recently converted my web app from VB to C#. There is one remaining issue - after the conversion, ***the CSS applied to the navigation menu in my Site.Master is no longer working***. It's behaving as though there is no CSS at all.

I have done the following:

- I've verified the CSS syntax
- I've removed and re-added the .css file
- I've removed and re-added the reference to the .css in the Site.Master
- I've copied the contents to another .css file and updated the reference
- I've created another test project and over the contents of the Site.Master from the main project, with the .css file, and verified that the CSS and references are indeed valid

**So my question is this:** Is there somewhere in an ASP.Net Web Application where CSS can be disabled for only some parts of an app?

This issue only occurs now, after the conversion, and the syntax is valid in other web projects, so it seems to me that it MUST have switched something in the application itself that is breaking it.

**Here's my code, somewhat cleaned up:**

My markup:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    ...
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    ...
</head>
<body>
...
    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="False" IncludeStyleBlock="False"
                Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="1">
        <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="PTS Home" Value="PTS Main" NavigateUrl="Default.aspx">...</asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Admin" Value="Admin">...</asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Estimating" Value="Estimating">...</asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Purchasing" Value="Purchasing">...</asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Commissions" Value="Commissions">...</asp:MenuItem>
            ...
        </Items>
    </asp:Menu>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
div.menu
{
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-color: #507F6D;
    z-index: 1;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 1px;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #37725C; 
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

What it should look like

[image: Correct appearance]

What it actually looks like

[image: Incorrect appearance]

Comment: Post some code, like this i don't think someone can help you

Comment: post the link to the css file as it appears in your site.master.  Also when you view the source of the web page and then click on the link to the css file, what happens?

Comment: Done. When I click the link, I am greeted the correct CSS file.

Comment: does the `asp:menu` create a `div` with a class of menu?  I would have just expected it create the `ul` tree but I've never used an `asp:menu` control before

Comment: You might be on to something, actually - the old version and the test version do create divs, but the converted version is creating a table structure. I'll need to look some.

Comment: I updated the question to be more descriptive of the actual issue, and help future people with the same problem. I've posted the solution as an answer and will mark it correct when I am able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, thanks to Pete's comments steering me in the right direction.

The  control's RenderingMode was set to "Default" - evidently, in VB the default behavior is List, but in C# it's Table. Div CSS is useless on  items, so no formatting. Set it to List and magic!

Answer (score 0):

```
div.menu
{
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-color: #507F6D;
    z-index: 1;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 1px;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

div.menu ul li a
{
    background-color: #37725C; 
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 5px;
    border: 1px solid greenyellow;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #37725C; 
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the div. in your CSS, i think that the control doesn't create a div

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ms366731(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: It does appear to be related - The converted program is creating tables with td elements. However, the brand-new test application creates a div, so it looks like there's probably a setting somewhere that determines how the menu is constructed.

Comment: If you remove the div the rule will be applied to every element with class="menu" not only the one under a div, thats why i wrote this. have you tryed?

Comment: I'd rather not alter the structure of the CSS if it's not necessary, and I found the answer to my problem, and have posted it as the answer.